# Date ValidationError

Tags: python, html, django

Am designing a project with a custom search, which at list two conditions must be met, e.g (input text and select tag option) or (input text and date option).

Presently searching with input text and date option works but if i search with input text and select tag option i get these error,

```
[u"'' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]
```

Here is my model:

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order_type            = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    certification_no      = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="43534")
    client                = models.ForeignKey(Client, blank=True, null=True)
    item                  = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    quantity              = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    item_value            = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=7)
    certification_type    = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    packing_list          = models.FileField(upload_to='files/%Y-%m-%d', blank=True, null=True)

    order                 = models.ForeignKey('Order', blank=True, null=True)
    created_on            = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

Here is my form.py:

```
class OrderItemForm(ModelForm): 
    class Meta:
        model  =   OrderItem
        fields = ['client','item','quantity', 'item_value', 
        'certification_type', 'packing_list', 'certification_no']
```

Here is my views:

```
def search_form(request):

    data = OrderItem.objects.order_by().values_list('certification_type', flat=True).distinct()
    print data

    if request.method == 'GET':
        user_search = request.GET.get('searched_item')
        print "What is searched for is : ", user_search

        selected_tag = request.GET.get('certification_type')
        print "The selected certificate type is :", selected_tag

        start_date = request.GET.get('first_date')
        print "The start date is : ", start_date

        end_date = request.GET.get('second_date')
        print "The end date is : ", end_date

        if user_search != None and (start_date != None or end_date != None or selected_tag !=None):
            items = OrderItem.objects.filter(
                (Q(certification_type__iexact=selected_tag) | Q(created_on__range=(start_date , end_date)) ) , 
                Q(order_type__iexact= user_search) | Q(item__iexact= user_search)
                 | Q(certification_no__iexact= user_search) | Q(client__user__email__iexact= user_search) | Q(client__phone_number__iexact= user_search) 
                 | Q(id__iexact= user_search) | Q(created_on__iexact= user_search)
                 )


            print "items  ",  items
            return render(request, 'i/search_results.html', {'items':items, 'user_search_query':user_search, 'selected_tag_query': selected_tag, "data":data, "start_date": start_date, "end_date": end_date})

        else:
            return render(request, 'i/dashboard.html', {'error':True,  "data":data})

    else:
        return render(request, 'i/dashboard.html', {'error':True,  "data":data})

    return render(request, 'i/search_results.html', {'items':items, 'user_search_query':user_search, 'selected_tag_query': selected_tag, "data":data})
```

don't know what am doing wrong,

Comment: Side note: Your `if user_search != None and (start_date != None or end_date != None or selected_tag !=None)` can be replaced with `if user_search and any([start_date, end_date, selected_tag])` Also, you are doing `Q(created_on__iexact= user_search)` which is incorrect - why would you search created_on with a search string ?

Comment: did as u suggested but it didn't work

Comment: I never gave you a solution.  I asked you why you are searching on a date field with a user string?

Answer (score 0):

In view :

not `user_search != None`you should use `user_search != ''`
and in forms.py use this sample for handel error:

```
def clean_user_search(self):
    test = self.cleaned_data.get('Name')

    if test != '':
        raise ValidationError('error')
    return test
```

Comment: will the clean user function be placed in the forms.py or views.py @Ramin

Comment: you should create clean_"filedname" for validation and in html {% if lst.errors.filedname %} display error to user